# AngularJS input type hidden with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, hidden

I'm developing an app and I've a table populated with `ng-repeat` and the last column of the table is an image that it is clicked open another page that should contains more details about the line of the table that I've choose clicking the image.

I've tried to use an input type hidden in a form but it doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Data in response">
                    <td align="center">{{Data.date}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{Data.conf}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{Data.evaso}}</td>
                    <form ng-submit="submit()">
                        <input type="hidden" name="codice" value="Data.code" ng-model="codice">
                        <td align="center"><input type="image" src="img/note.png" class="imageNote" ng-click="submit()"></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
```

After in the controller I need to manage this data (the cod). But in this way, I've tried to print it in the console and the result is `undefined`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does the type=image call the submit function? You should check that. Your function should $scope.submit

Comment: yes the image call the submit function correctly @Kermani

Comment: Your codice variable will save the same data as Data.code. In other terms codice = Data.code?

Comment: You want to have the selected item in your submit, right? Then my answer should work! But if you needed something else, please let me know maybe I am just confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question, but if you want to pass the selected item to the submit function, you can have your angular function like this:

```
$scope.submit = function(selectedId){
   console.log(selectedId);
   //Your code.
}
```

and your HTML should change to this:

```
<input ng-click="submit(Data.id)" type="image" src="img/note.png" class="imageNote">
```

*Note: You do not need to use `{{}}` (expressions) to pass something to a function (here, ng-click)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try following way to get easily the Date.code data on click:

```
<input type="image" src="img/note.png" class="imageNote" ng-click="submit(Data.code)">
```